# Muti threading and multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to read a csv file and calculate the time required for linear processing, using threads and multiprocessing but my code doesn't seems to get me the correct output. It would be great if someone could help me with the codes.

Multi processing and Linear Processing:

```
import csv
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process

proces=[]
number_of_processes=2


class mulprocess():

    def data(self):

        with open('test.csv','r+') as f:

            reader=csv.reader(f)

            for row in reader:                  
                print row


    def processdata(self):

        for i in range(2):

            start_time=time.time()

            proces.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=self.data(),args=()))

        for p in proces:

            p.start()

        for p in proces:

            p.join()

        end_time=time.time()

        print end_time-start_time

a=mulprocess()
a.data()
a.processdata()
```

Threading:

```
import csv
import time
import threading

thread_count=2
threads=[]

class Operation():

    def data(self):

        with open('test.csv','r+') as f:

            reader=csv.reader(f)

            for row in reader:
                print row


    def filedata(self):

        for i in range(thread_count):

            threads.append(threading.Thread(target=self.data,args=()))

        start_time=time.time()

        for t in threads:

            t.start()            
            t.join()

        end_time=time.time()

        print end_time-start_time


a=Operation()    
a.filedata()
```

Comment: Why do you want multiple processes for reading data from disk?

Comment: What if he has 2 disks? :) What if it involves processing the data a little or more?

Comment: Anyway, don't bother with threads, as they don't make good parallel computation possible because of GIL. Only use threads when you want another thread to do something while the first one is waiting for stuff (like input, or a HTTP response)

Comment: @AlexanderMP That might be plausible if the file wasn't hard-coded in the function to be multiprocessed. I think multiple access is more hassle than it's worth and probably won't go any faster anyway

Comment: I would like to compute the differences in processing time for the 3 process with different no of threads/process.
My csv file has 2 lakh rows with 40 columns so I wiuld like to try both multithreading and multi processing

Comment: But how will this help speed things up? It's not a CPU-bound task.

Comment: Multithreading has already been explained in terms of the GIL, so that won't help. And each process in multiprocessing gets its own memory so if anything, you double the load on memory unless you get the processes to read different sections of the file.

Comment: The problem is i dont know where to apply thread count and no of process, I have added it to a for loop and so the file reads n times.
but i want the file to be read once and n number of threads or process should be applied to it.

Comment: Are you reading the feedback we've given?

Comment: Ya I'm reading the comments and I can understand that threading would be of no use as its CPU bound task.
By using linear processing it takes 300 secs and when I try to read the file once with 2 process, the file gets read twice so it takes nearly 800 seconds whereas it should take less than 400 secs as its reading file once and using 2 process.
Help me to correct my code to read once and apply n number of processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the pointlessness of loading the same file over and over in a different process (which, btw. might can cause concurrency error because you're loading your file in `r+` mode, effectively locking it) and the general ill-advised approach of calling instance methods as separate processes, the crux of your problem lies in the line:

```
proces.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=self.data(), args=()))
```

What you're telling the `multiprocessing.Process` instance there is to set the `target` to whatever your `self.data()` method returns, which is `None`, so your process doesn't get anything to work with or to call so everything executes in your main process and, of course, it takes double the time. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525554/7553525) to see how to set up multiprocessing benchmark properly.

As for `threading` - no reason to try it out, it will be slower for processing than a single-threaded approach. The only advantage you can have with threading is semi-parallelizing I/O operations.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. Can you explain about how to achieve semi-parallelizing i/o operations using threads??

Comment: @anonymous - while Python (CPython at least) uses real system threads when you use `threading.Thread`, due to the dreaded GIL you cannot have more than one of those threads running at the same time no matter of how many CPUs you have on your system. This means that, effectively, Python threads don't run in parallel (there are certain exceptions but nothing of importance for the matter at hand). However, GIL can be released while your thread is waiting for I/O operations (say, reading a file or waiting for a network resource) so your whole app doesn't get blocked while you're loading something.

Comment: As for how - you already got it, however you're loading the same file (potentially blocking other loads) so of course you won't get any speed up - all your threads would be waiting for the same resource in a sense. Also, any additional processing you add to the threads will actually be slower (due to context switches and similar things) than if you were to run it all in a single thread.

Comment: If i read the file from some database like Mongodb or MySQL, I can apply threading right as it wont be a CPU bound process??

Comment: @anonymous - as long as you're reading different data and don't post-process it too much, sure, threads can help alleviate the pain of blocking your whole app while loading the data from resources that incur latencies like databases.