# python script is slowly after use multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i have create an image processing python function.

my system have 4 cores + 4 threads.

i want to use multiprocessing to speed up my function,but anytime to use multiprocessing packages my function is not faster and is 1 minute slowly.
any idea why ?first time use multiprocessing packages.

main function :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/in.tif"
    out_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/out.tif"
    myfun(in_path, out_path)
```

time=3.4 minutes

with multiprocessing map :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(processes=4)
    in_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/in.tif"
    out_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/out.tif"
    result = p.map(myfun(in_path,out_path))
```

time=4.4 minutes

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    in_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/in.tif"
    out_path="C:/Users/username/Desktop/out.tif"
    pool.apply_async(myfun, args=(in_path,out_path,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

time=4.5 minutes

Comment: Right, so the problem is in `myfun()` which you don't show us.

Comment: @JohnZwinck so multiprocessing is for specific functions only?

Comment: Why don't you show us the code and let us decide?

Answer (score 1):

`multiprocessing.Pool.map()` does not automatically make a function run in parallel. So doing `Pool.map(my_function(single_input))` will not make it run any faster. In fact, it may make it slower.

The purpose of `map()` is to allow you to run the same function *multiple times* in parallel if you have *multiple inputs*.

If you had:

```
in_paths = ['C:/Users/in1.tif', 'C:/Users/in2.tif', ... ]
out_paths = ['C:/Users/out1.tif', 'C:/Users/out2.tif', ... ]
```

Then you could use `Pool.map()` to speed up your program, for example:

```
p = Pool(4)
results = p.map(my_function, zip(in_paths, out_paths))
```

But since you have a single input, you only need to run your function once, and so there is no difference. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing the same function with the same parameters in a sub-process - this is bound to be slower as, at the very least, there is a system overhead of creating a new process, and then comes the Python's own overhead. It creates a whole new interpreter, stack, GIL... and that takes time.

On POSIX systems this overhead is a bit faster as it can use forking and copy-on-write memory, but on Windows this is essentially as if you called `python -c "from your_script import myfun; myfun('C:/Users/username/Desktop/in.tif', 'C:/Users/username/Desktop/out.tif')"` from the command line and that takes a considerable amount of time.

You'll notice benefits of multiprocessing only if you have considerable computation requirements which can be parallelized from your function. Check a simple benchmark in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525554/7553525).

Comment: if i use this your proposal its the some time again

Comment: @user27818 - It's not about showing an example, I explained you why does it take longer to run your function as a separate process. It will always be like that, to get the advantage of multiprocessing you'll have to run multiple processes at once (preferably at most the number of processes will match the number of available CPU cores for your processing). The link to the other answer I gave shows that explicitly via `multiprocessing.Pool.map()`.

Comment: you say me to Break myfunc to sub-myfunc like myfunc1,myfunc2,myfunc3,myfunc3  ?

Comment: @user27818 - no, I'm saying call your function with a multiple set of arguments in different sub-processes (you can use `multiprocessing.Pool` to manage that for you). If you're calling only one sub-process of course it will run slower than running everything in your main process.

Comment: i cant understand you