# How to get speed by multiprocessing in Python (linux), insteed of losing

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I search the way to use all cores. But all I try, only decrease spreed.

I tried following:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
from time import time
import numpy as np

inputs = range(1000)

def processInput(i):
    return i * i
```

using multiprocessing

```
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

start=time()
results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(processInput)(i) for i in inputs)
print 'multiproc time ', time()-start
```

without multiprocessing

```
start=time()

results =[]
for i in inputs:
    results.append(processInput(i))

print 'simple time ', time()-start
```

and get output:

```
multiproc time 0.14687204361
simple time 0.000839948654175
```

Comment: what about asyncio?

Comment: It takes time for subprocesses to initialize, and whenever you exchange data between processes it gets pickled at one end and unpickled at the other. To properly utilize multiprocessing design your system so that your processes perform a grunt of calculation on their own and do as little data exchange as possible. Check [this little benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525554/7553525) to see multiprocessing in 'full' effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem with multi-threading / multi-processing. Whenever you want to process something in parallel, you should make sure that the time you are saving because of parallelism is greater than the time it takes to manage parallel processes.

Try increasing the input size. Then you will see the impact of parallelism.