# Parallelizing through Multi-threading and Multi-processing taking significantly more time than serial

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn how to do parallel programming in python. I wrote a simple int square function and then ran it in serial, multi-thread, and multi-process:

```
import time
import multiprocessing, threading
import random


def calc_square(numbers):
    sq = 0
    for n in numbers:
        sq = n*n

def splita(list, n):
    a = [[] for i in range(n)]
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0,len(list)):
        a[counter].append(list[i])
        if len(a[counter]) == len(list)/n:
            counter = counter +1
            continue
    return a


if __name__ == "__main__":

    random.seed(1)
    arr = [random.randint(1, 11) for i in xrange(1000000)]
    print "init completed"

    start_time2 = time.time()
    calc_square(arr)
    end_time2 = time.time()

    print "serial: " + str(end_time2 - start_time2)

    newarr = splita(arr,8)
    print 'split complete'

    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(8):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=calc_square, args=(newarr[i],))

        t1.start()
        t1.join()

    end_time = time.time()

    print "mt: " + str(end_time - start_time)

    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(8):
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square, args=(newarr[i],))
        p1.start()
        p1.join()

    end_time = time.time()

    print "mp: " + str(end_time - start_time)
```

Output:

```
init completed
serial: 0.0640001296997
split complete
mt: 0.0599999427795
mp: 2.97099995613
```

However, as you can see, something weird happened and mt is taking the same time as serial and mp is actually taking significantly longer (almost 50 times longer).

What am I doing wrong? Could someone push me in the right direction to learn parallel programming in python?

**Edit 01**

Looking at the comments, I see that perhaps the function not returning anything seems pointless. The reason I'm even trying this is because previously I tried the following add function:

```
def addi(numbers):
    sq = 0
    for n in numbers:
        sq = sq + n
    return sq
```

I tried returning the addition of each part to a serial number adder, so at least I could see some performance improvement over a pure serial implementation. However, I couldn't figure out how to store and use the returned value, and that's the reason I'm trying to figure out something even simpler than that, which is just dividing up the array and running a simple function on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You create thread, start it, and wait until it completes its work. Why should this be faster than performing the same work in the main thread? And yes, creating a thread is not a fast operation.

Comment: You repeat your `multiprocessing` calculation 8 times. Plus the overhead of spawning a process. Either divvy up the work beforehand and pass each process a chunk, or use a `pool`. Threading will not speed up CPU-bound tasks due to the GIL.

Comment: So how should I run the threads in parallel?

Comment: I've experimented with this and I get the same results, even after allowing for creating all the `Processes`

Comment: @roganjosh I ran the same function on 8 different parts of the array. How do I use a pool or pass each process a chunk?

Comment: `calc_square` currently doesn't return anything. I think there's a flaw in your code outside the benchmarking. I'm looking at it now

Comment: @roganjosh: `calc_square` is just a make-work function.

Comment: @quamrana but a realistic make-work function should also return a result. I'm working on adapting the code so that the function is mapped across the input list. Then serial/multiprocessing can be assessed fairly.

Comment: @quamrana in other words, I don't dispute what you're saying, but the benchmark might as well be representative of real work that you might want to do.

Comment: @roganjosh right, previously I did try an add function as well. I was trying to serially add an array and then parallelly add it. Making an edit to show exactly what I tried.

Comment: Here's a simple benchmark proving multiprocessing speedup if you set it up correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525554/7553525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `multiprocessing` takes quite a long time to create and start each process. I have changed the program to make 10 times the size of `arr` and changed the way that the processes are started and there is a slight speed-up:

*(Also note python 3)*

```
import time
import multiprocessing, threading
from multiprocessing import Queue
import random

def calc_square_q(numbers,q):
    while q.empty():
        pass
    return calc_square(numbers)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    random.seed(1)   # note how big arr is now vvvvvvv
    arr = [random.randint(1, 11) for i in range(10000000)]
    print("init completed")

    # ...
    # other stuff as before
    # ...

    processes=[]
    q=Queue()
    for arrs in newarr:
        processes.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_square_q, args=(arrs,q)))

    print('start processes')
    for p in processes:
        p.start()  # even tho' each process is started it waits...

    print('join processes')
    q.put(None)   # ... for q to become not empty.
    start_time = time.time()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    end_time = time.time()

    print("mp: " + str(end_time - start_time))
```

Also notice above how I create and start the processes in two different loops, and then finally join with the processes in a third loop.

Output:

```
init completed
serial: 0.53214430809021
split complete
start threads
mt: 0.5551605224609375
start processes
join processes
mp: 0.2800724506378174
```

Another factor of 10 increase in size of `arr`:

```
init completed
serial: 5.8455305099487305
split complete
start threads
mt: 5.411392450332642
start processes
join processes
mp: 1.9705185890197754
```

And yes, I've also tried this in python 2.7, although `Threads` seemed slower.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, would this also work in 2.7x? That's what I'm using.

Comment: Throws a "NameError: name 'Queue' is not defined" error. What should I do? Tried importing Queue, throws a not-callable error then.

Comment: I only used the `Queue` to demonstrate how much time it takes to start processes. It might not be needed at all for a parallel processing job.

Comment: In fact, most of the time might be taken up with passing the large arrays into each of the processes.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I understand this correctly, it was important to create all the processes first and only then run them in order to properly calculate the time improvement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160823/discussion-between-user241691-and-quamrana).