# Multiprocessing Map takes longer than serial

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have 2 sockets with each 20 cores so I would like to speed up some processes. But multiprocess are always slower than the serial "approach". Is there a reason for that? Am I not doing this the most efficient way? Is it due to a lack of communication (pipe or queue) between processes?

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np

#Classical approach by serial
startime = time.time()
def f(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)
f(np.arange(1000))
print("---%s seconds ---" % (time.time() - startime))

#Multiprocess test
startime = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(40)
    test = p.map(np.sqrt,np.arange(1000),chunksize=1)
print("---%s seconds ---" % (time.time() - startime))
```

---- EDIT ---

With parallel i need 2.92 sec and in serial i need less 1 sec...

Comment: It takes time to create 40 processes and to distribute data chunks to them (the whole pickle/unpickle routine). Multiprocessing makes little sense for very short-duration processes. If you had a far more complex function than pulling a square root you'd notice the difference as demonstrated, for example, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525554/7553525).

Answer (score 1):

Starting processes is slow, even on a modern OS.
Calculating 1000 square roots is *blazing* fast on modern hardware.

To reap benefits of parallel processing, you have to spend much more time on actual computation than on starting things up. Try computing something more expensive, like 1000 `bcrypt`s, or slow, like hitting 1000 different URLs.

With compute-intensive tasks, where every process eats 100% CPU, there's no point to have more processes than CPU cores.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have to work on important array close to 2000x2000x700. I suppose it makes sense to use parallel processing?

Comment: It makes sense to describe your problem in detail first. Maybe parallel processing, as shown here, would be a good fit. Maybe you want something entirely different. I suppose you've already looked at `numpy`, `pandas`, or maybe even `pyspark`? Chances are they may have a solution, or key parts of a solution, to your real problem.

Comment: It is for a specific use in tomography with important 3D images

Comment: @user3601754: but what kind of computation do you plan to do on your images? E.g. for parallel processing, the computation should be splittable into independent parts. If it's images, have you also looked at OpenCV?

Comment: Currently i m trying to extract lines in my 2D radiographies at different angles in order to plot sinogram. That is why i think i could split my list of images and dispatch "computations". Is it fit for multiprocess?

Comment: If you can split your data so that you can independently work on parts of it, it's a good fit for parallel processing. Even if you need the _whole_ dataset for each process, but each process does a different thing with it, it's still a good fit. Pure Python is not great for numerics, though; you almost necessarily want numpy / scipy / pandas for efficient numerical processing of large data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ;) I will try that!